# XML to HTML tags conversion

Tags: html, xml, parsing

The problem lies in the character encoding of XML. 
The situation looks like this:

1. Saving text to the SQL database with HTML tags 
   `<p> Example </ p>`
2. Reading the text from the database using an XML parser - character conversion to XML 
   `&lt;p&gt;Example&lt;/p&gt;`
3. I put the text in the HTML file and the problem is that the text does not format to HTML. 
   It's displayed inside the quotation marks with HTML tags. `"<p> Example </p>"`

For a long time I can not find any solutions. Can you suggest something?

Comment: Which Database technology are you using?

Comment: You need to use something else to encode that text from database to HTML. Are you using any programming language for this task?